# Include VTK dir as System include in Cmake

Tags: cmake, vtk

I have a project that uses VTK as an external library. In my own source code, is use `-Werror` to ensure that those are always fixed. In order to do this "checking" in my code, external libraries are loaded in CMake with the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` directive using the parameter `SYSTEM`. But if some external library is loaded through a `CMakeLists.txt` file (as VTK is)? I cannot specify that specify that VTK is a `SYSTEM` library and therefore VTK warnings are shown as errors. **Is there a way to disable warnings from included libraries?**

Comment: how do You "include" the `CMakeLists.txt` file? Are you using the [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:include) command?

Comment: this is the way that external libraries that use cmake on their structures (such as VTK, ITK) may be included:`INCLUDE(${VTK_USE_FILE})`

Comment: for a non cmakelist library such as Qt I can load it in my CmakeList using the directive INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES using the parameter SYSTEM that indicates that those headers are from the system (this way the compiler does not verify warnings from these "external" headers)

Answer (score 2):

VTK adds `include_directories` itself, so unless you change VTK's CMake file with that line, you will most probably have to change your included directories property with [some string operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031127/cmake-remove-include-directory). A faster way that worked for me is to change the line in VTK with `include_directories`, namely `lib/cmake/vtk-*/UseVTK.cmake` - the one you include with `include(${VTK_USE_FILE})`. I just changed the line

```
# Add include directories needed to use VTK.
include_directories(${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

to

```
# Add include directories needed to use VTK.
include_directories(SYSTEM ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

and it seems to have squelched the warnings from VTK header files by [marking them as `SYSTEM` libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can insert `include_directories(SYSTEM ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})` instructions right after the `find_package` instructions.

```
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
```